# Fixing address on TeleAtlas, how long before Google Maps has this information?

Tags: google-maps, address

I recently submitted information to TeleAtlas and they told me it was accepted and has been added.

When I search on Google Maps the address still does not appear.

Does anyone know how long Google Maps take to update with new information or it just a matter of TeleAtlas making the data available for Google?

Comment: Are you sure that TeleAtlas provide the map data to Google in your area? in the UK and the US Google use their own data.

Comment: When I'm over my town, Google Maps has this on the bottom right.

Imagery (C)2012 DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Mao data (C)2012 Tele Atlas

Comment: In an e-mail from TeleAtlas they said "We were able to use your input to improve our maps. This update will go out in our next release of our map database."

Comment: It can range from the 6 months teleAtlas cycle to when ever google do a re-tile of all 17 maptile levels (approx 18-24 months). Satellite and Aerial Images are updated one week after Google Earth - monthly, 3 monthly cycle (but localised areas only).